# How to merge one XML file with data into one big text file using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

My XML looks like this:

```
<NewDataSet>
  <Table>
    <Column1>"Date = "2017/11/10", ImageType = "A", Doctype = "ABC", DOCTYPE_DESCR = "ABC data file", Total = "2"</Column1>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Column1>"Date = "2017/11/10", ImageType = "b", Doctype = "DEF", DOCTYPE_DESCR = "DEF chart file", Total = "2"</Column1>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Column1>"Date = "2017/11/10", ImageType = "C", Doctype = "HIJ", DOCTYPE_DESCR = "HIJ PDF ", Total = "2"</Column1>
  </Table>
  <Table>
    <Column1>"Date = "2017/11/10", ImageType = "d", Doctype = "KLM", DOCTYPE_DESCR = "KLM file.", Total = "1"</Column1>
  </Table>
</NewDataSet>
```

Here's my desired output text file. Currently, my program is outputting individual text files rather than one single text files with the multiple results. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
"Date = "2017/11/10", ImageType = "A", Doctype = "ABC", DOCTYPE_DESCR = "ABC data file", Total = "2"
"Date = "2017/11/10", ImageType = "B", Doctype = "DEF", DOCTYPE_DESCR = "DEF chart file", Total = "2"
"Date = "2017/11/10", ImageType = "C", Doctype = "HIJ", DOCTYPE_DESCR = "HIJ PDF", Total = "2"
"Date = "2017/11/10", ImageType = "D", Doctype = "KLM", DOCTYPE_DESCR = "KLM file", Total = "1"
```

Here's my XSLT

```
  <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"> 
   <xsl:output method="text" indent="yes"/>  
    <!--match the root node-->
    <xsl:template match="NewDataSet">
    </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is your XSLT complete? You have a close ` </xsl:element>` tag, but no opening one. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you want to transform most elements only by transforming their child elements.  The exception is `<Column1>` elements, which you want to transform as text nodes containing the elements' string values, possibly with a newline appended.

Comment: In any case, nothing remotely like the (invalid) transform you presented will transform your input into multiple files.  What you may have seen instead with your actual transform is all the whitespace (including newlines) between tags in the input document being copied into the output.

Comment: How do you apply/execute the transformation? Which tool asre you using? Can you show the commandline?

Answer (score 0):

If using `XSLT 2.0` is an option, you can employ method `xsl:result-document`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsl:template match="NewDataSet">
        <xsl:result-document method="text" href="NewDataSet.txt">
            <xsl:for-each select="/NewDataSet/Table/Column1">                               
                <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>       
        </xsl:result-document>
    </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-result-document